# Remove -1 like when the button is pressed again

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have already asked a question about how to update the number of likes, I do not know if this option is correct, but nevertheless the number of likes is updated.

Now I have difficulties in another place, if I click on the like button, then +1 Like is added, but if I click the button again, another +1 Like will be added and so on indefinitely, but I'm trying to make it so that if I click again, the number of Likes will decrease by -1

I tried to use `.disabled(islike)` but it forbids clicking on the button again, how can I implement this? I use Firebase Firestore, ios15

My Code:

CellLike.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct CellLike: View {
    
    @Binding var isLike: Bool
    @State private var animate = false
    private let animationDuration: Double = 0.1
    private var animationScale: CGFloat {
        isLike ? 0.7 : 1.3
    }
    @ObservedObject var data = getData()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            if self.data.data != nil {
                
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        self.animate = true
                        /// Add +1 Like
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("Like").document("Option").updateData(["ss" : FieldValue.increment(1.0) ])
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.animationDuration) {
                            self.animate = false
                            self.isLike.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: isLike ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(isLike ? .red : .gray)
                    }
                    .scaleEffect(animate ? animationScale : 1)
                    .animation(.easeIn(duration: animationDuration), value: animate)
//                    .disabled(isLike)
                    /// Number like
                    Text("\(self.data.data.like)")
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .onReceive(timer) { update in
                            self.data.updateData()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct Datas {
    var like: Int
}

class getData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: Datas!
    
    init() {
        updateData()
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("Like").document("Option").getDocument { (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            let like = snap?.get("ss") as! Int
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = Datas(like: like)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LikeButtonView.swift

```
struct LikeButtonView: View {
    @AppStorage("isLike") private var isLike = false
    var body: some View {
        CellLike(isLike: $isLike)
    }
}
```

My Firestore database collection:
[image]

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: First toggle isLike and after that check it if you should send +1 or -1 to Firebase. (And you don't need to use DispatchQueue when updating a State or Binding property in SwiftUI)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you help me do this with my example? I'm studying and I don't know much.

Comment: Move `self.isLike.toggle()` to the top of the Button action and then when calling `updateData` change the increment call to `FieldValue.increment(isLike ? 1.0: -1.0)`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you very much! It works! And you also talked about `DispatchQueue.main.async`, can I delete it from `func updateData()` or from the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On start of your button action you have to do **isLike.toggle** like this:

```
Button {

        self.isLike.toggle()

        self.animate = true
        /// Add +1 Like
         Firestore.firestore().collection("Like").document("Option").updateData(["ss" : FieldValue.increment(isLike ? 1.0: -1.0) ])
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.animationDuration) {
              self.animate = false           
            }
       } label: {

              Image(systemName: isLike ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                   .resizable()
                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                   .frame(width: 60)
                   .foregroundColor(isLike ? .red : .gray)
      }
```

Comment: Yes it works, but now it causes flickering, see the -> [link](https://i.ibb.co/tMTvWfd/ezgif-com-gif-maker.gif)

Comment: I don't understand what this is related to, I even tried to disable the update timer, but it didn't help

Comment: I found out that this happens because of `if self.data.data != nil { }` but if I remove this property, how can I display the number of likes differently?